# If I add phone number to my HTML form, the add new hire button gets disable. Is there a limit to put html elements?

Tags: html

Following is the html code. All I wanted to know if there are limits to putting html elements for form designing.

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Add New Employee</h1>
    <br>

    <form action="process.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Full Name:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="permanent_address">Permanent Address:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="permanent_address">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="marital_status">Marital Status:</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="marital_status">
                <option value="Married">Married</option>
                <option value="Unmarried">Unmarried</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="gender">Gender: </label>
            <input type="radio" value="Male" name="train">Male
            <input type="radio" value="Female" name="train">Female
        </div>

        This is where the problem starts.
        This is the reason i've disable phone number by commenting it becasue it is disabling the submit button.

        <!-- <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phone">Phone number: </label>    
            <input class="form-control" type="number" name="phone">
        </div> --> 

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="admission_date">Admission Date: </label>
            <input type="date" name="admission_date">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Aadhar">Aadhar Number: </label>
            <input class = "form-control" name="Aadhar">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success" name="submitted">Add New Hire</button>
    </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code seems to run fine.  There are no limits to how many elements you can have in a form - possibly limited my memory.  Why do you think your form isn't working?

also for phone input try the following:

```
   <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone"
   pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"
   required>
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>Add New Employee</h1>
    <br>

    <form action="https://www.google.com" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Full Name:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="permanent_address">Permanent Address:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="permanent_address">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="marital_status">Marital Status:</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="marital_status">
                <option value="Married">Married</option>
                <option value="Unmarried">Unmarried</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="gender">Gender: </label>
            <input type="radio" value="Male" name="train">Male
            <input type="radio" value="Female" name="train">Female
        </div>

        This is where the problem starts.
        This is the reason i've disable phone number by commenting it becasue it is disabling the submit button.

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phone">Phone number: </label>    
            <input class="form-control" type="number" name="phone">
        </div> 

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="admission_date">Admission Date: </label>
            <input type="date" name="admission_date">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Aadhar">Aadhar Number: </label>
            <input class = "form-control" name="Aadhar">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success" name="submitted">Add New Hire</button>
    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: I am running it on PHP server. I've also integrated this page with MySQL PHPmyadmin. Just the button isnt getting clicked for submitting.